# Setting a default parent page

Tags: page-attributes

I have a site I'm putting together for a friend and I would like all new pages that are created to be the children of a set page (page id 495). I assume that I need to edit the meta-boxes.php file but not sure other than that.

Can anyone help me with this? I'd appreciate any comments.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

This hooks onto the `wp_insert_post_data` filter, and checks if the post to be inserted is both a page and an auto-draft (which happens when you first create a new post/page).

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_59007_set_default_page_parent' );
function wpse_59007_set_default_page_parent( $data )
{
    if ( $data['post_status'] == 'auto-draft' && $data['post_type'] == 'page' )
        $data['post_parent'] = 495;
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would also like to set the page template default to a desired template you can do so with:

```
function set_default_page_template() {
  global $post;
  if ( 'page' == $post->post_type && 0 != count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID ) {
         $post->page_template = "your_template_file_name.php";
}
```